# Getting setInterval to work through child elements in a html list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the `setInterval()` method to try apply a class to each individual `li`.

I've created a jsFiddle that applies the toggleClass but I cannot get it to apply the class one by one.

Below is my javaScript, I've also added a link to the jsFiddle:

```
var i = 1;
var id = setInterval(function () {
    $("ul").children(i).toggleClass('test');
    i++;
    if (i === 4) {
        i = 1;
    }
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Svx3n/42/

Comment: First index starts at zero, not one.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues that I spot:

When working with indexes, the index starts at zero, not one.

[`.children(\[selector\])`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) does not take an index, it takes a selector. So you are asking jQuery to find the element of type of one. Instead use `.eq(index)` to get the element.

So the changes to your code would be:

```
var i = 0;
var id = setInterval(function () {

    $("ul").children().eq(i).toggleClass('test');

    i++;

    if (i === 4) {
        i = 0;
    }

}, 1000);
```

Better yet, move the selecting out so you are not doing the querying of the DOM every iteration

```
var i = 0,
    lis = $("ul").children(),
    id = window.setInterval( function () {    
            lis.eq(i).toggleClass('test');    
            i++;    
            if (i === 4) {
                i = 0;
            }    
         }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ":nth-child" in conjunction with "i"

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Svx3n/43/)**

```
var i = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function () {

        $("ul li").eq(i).toggleClass('test');
        i++;
        if (i === 4) {
            i = 0;
        }

    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var i = 0, $lis = $("ul li");
var id = setInterval(function () {
    $lis.eq(i).toggleClass('test');
    i++;

    i = i % $lis.length;
}, 1000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zFVrn/)